# 3 columns image layout with image text

Tags: html, css

I need three columns of image layout with image text like this picture
its responsive, like below picture no border no background color, image text background color like this required, I'm new to css/html

I need three columns of image layout with image text like this picture
its responsive, like below picture no border no background color, image text background color like this required, I'm new to css/html

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.figure {
    border: thin #c0c0c0 solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 220px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.imgdiv {
    max-width: 220px;
    max-height: 150px;
}

.figcaption {
    background-color: pink;
    color: #fff;
    font: italic smaller sans-serif;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Responsive Three Column Layout</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect (the columns will stack on top of each other instead of floating next to each other, when the screen is less than 600px wide).</p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="">
    <figure>
    <img class="column" src="image1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <figcaption>Register here</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h3>image 2</h3>
    <p>Info 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h3>Publications</h3>
    <p>Info 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: like always: DON'T use `float` for styling purpose. Use `Flexbox` or in this case `CSS-Grid` instead. `float` is for floating images within a paragraph only not to place elements next to each other

Comment: pls help me with script

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex` and `flex-direction`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.column {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  /* padding: 0.1rem; */
}

.caption h3,
.caption p {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Responsive Three Column Layout</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect (the columns will stack on top of each other instead of floating next to each other, when the screen is less than 600px wide).</p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" alt="arctichare">
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>image 1</h3>
      <p>Info 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>image 2</h3>
      <p>Info 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png" alt="baboon">
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Publications</h3>
      <p>Info 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i need 3 columns like picture i attached, image text and text background color also need please

Comment: just that you use `inline-block` and not actually `flex`

Comment: its great can you please try to put caption on bottom of image

Comment: The caption is on the bottom of image! I can't figure out what to do @user2235050